# Differential equation for ellipsoid

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the following differential equation:

\begin{equation}
\Delta f - \lambda^2((\Delta f)^2 - (\partial_i \partial_j f)^2) = g,
\end{equation}

where there is an implicit sum over i,j and $g$ is a function which is constant non-zero inside an ellipsoid and outside zero. Is there a way how to extract analytical solutions out of this? I tried in elliptical coordinates but that is tricky and for my purposes Cartesian coordinates would be more useful...

Comment: What is the equation of the ellipsoid?

Comment: It is a general triaxial ellispoid, i.e. $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 = 1$. I want to study a physical application with it and encountered this. $a=b=c$ case, i.e. a sphere is quite solvable for our purposes but I am now interested in where $a,b,c$ are all different (non-zero of course)